# How to Exclude Androidx or Force Not to Use Androidx Dependency in Android

Tags: android, google-places-autocomplete, android-x86

I am working on a project which is using some old libraries.It is working fine except the google place auto complete as it is depricated. As I am trying to integrate new google place library `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'` some dependency are starting to use `androidx` which is creating problems like `aapt errors and others` Below are the dependency that are coming from  `androidx` after new place library implementation.I want to keep the old stuffs with new place auto complete api.How can I exclude them or force not to use `androidx`

```
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0@aar
```

I have tried below in my app.gradle

```
implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'){
    exclude group: 'androidx.core', module: 'core'
}
```

and this inside android option

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/androidx.*'
    exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-*'
}
```

Also tried to force specific version in my project level build.gradle

```
 configurations {

 all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:11.8.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype:11.8.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
        forece 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:11.8.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0'

    }
  }
}
```

and below in my gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
```

But nothing working.How can I do this pls help

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off enabling androidx at this point. [API 29 is the minimum target SDK required on the Play Store as of date of this reply](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk), and API 29 is the start where the android-support -> androidx cutoff started.